# Refining a repeated method

Tags: java, javafx

I have method that is repeated in multiple combo-box's, and I'm not too sure if there is a way to generalise this to minimise repetition? Here is the method:

```
public void numberTicket1(){
        switch (no1.getValue().toString()){
            case "One":
                numberOfTickets = 1;
                break;
            case "Two":
                numberOfTickets = 2;
                break;
            case "Three":
                numberOfTickets = 3;
                break;
            case "Four":
                numberOfTickets = 4;
                break;
            case "Five":
                numberOfTickets = 5;
                break;
            case "Six":
                numberOfTickets = 6;
                break;
            default:
                numberOfTickets = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could init an immutable, utility `HashMap<String, Integer> numberStringToInt` and use `numberStringToInt.get(no1.getValue().toString())`.

Comment: You can use an enum if your value is known. Also, can you elaborate your question more in detail?

Answer (score 3):

```
numberOfTickets = Arrays.asList (
    "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six").
    indexOf (no1.getValue().toString()) + 1;
```